# In laravel why the additional packages are stored in vendor directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to change the floder for additional installed package.How to change the floder path for additional installed packages.

Comment: I install stevemo/cpanel package.I am able to find the stevemo folder under vendor directory.I want to change the stevemo folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is framework that depends on many other packages that has been built by the best in the PHP world and makes use of a dependency management tool called [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

For Laravel to work her `magic`, she needs the help of `composer` to download all those codes that has gone through the test of time to assist her. `composer` would then place all of these codes into a folder specifically tailored for them which is the `/vendor` folder.

It seems that you need the power of some other codes to help you in your project. If that's the case, you might want to check out [composer](https://getcomposer.org) first for some basics before starting a new Laravel project.

You might want to check [this video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/1) on https://laracasts.com to get a bigger picture as to how all of these things piece together.

**Update**

If you need to change the `/vendor` directory, you can simply change them in your `composer.json`.

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "new-vendor-dir-name"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.but i am not need change vendor directory.some packeges only i need to install in specified folder.

Comment: I'm not very sure why you would want to do that, but you can download those packages manually, put it in the specified folder and then include it through the autoloader.